# JavaScript clear text boxes DOM only clearing top box

Tags: javascript, html, button, submit

So I've got a set of text boxes which I have a clear button for, however when clicked, it only removes the text from the top box.  I was wondering if there was a way for all of the boxes to be removed in this way?

```
function eraseText() {
    document.getElementById("output").value = "";
}


var sections = {

  p1 : {sname: "Dynamic Table   ", mscore: 20},
  p2 : {sname: "IntelliJ Usage  ", mscore: 10},
  p3 : {sname: "Calender Control", mscore: 30},
  p4 : {sname: "Active Form     ", mscore: 20},
  p5 : {sname: "Object Database ", mscore: 20}
};

document.write("<pre>");
document.write(Object.keys(sections).reduce(function(s, p, i) {
   var o = sections[p];
   return s + (i>0?'<br><br><br><br>':'') + o.sname +  '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + o.mscore + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + '<textarea id="output" rows="4" cols="25">' + '</textarea>' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'}, '')
);
document.write("</pre>");
```

And then in HTML I have this submit button:

```
 <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="javascript:eraseText();">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrap it all in form tags, you could use

```
<input type="reset" />
```

If not, I would give them a class and code this:

```
function eraseText() {
    var out = document.querySelectorAll(".out");
    for (var i=0;i<out.length;i++) {
      out[i].value="";
    }
}
```

Looking at your code I would also change the use of document.write and remove the useless `javascript:` label

```
var sections = {
  p1 : {sname: "Dynamic Table   ", mscore: 20},
  p2 : {sname: "IntelliJ Usage  ", mscore: 10},
  p3 : {sname: "Calender Control", mscore: 30},
  p4 : {sname: "Active Form     ", mscore: 20},
  p5 : {sname: "Object Database ", mscore: 20}
};

document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=Object.keys(sections).reduce(
  function(s, p, i) {
   var o = sections[p];
   return s + (i>0?'<br><br><br><br>':'') + o.sname + 
    '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + 
    o.mscore + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + 
    '<textarea class="out" id="output" rows="4" cols="25"></textarea>' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
  }, '');
```

and give the container a css of

```
#container {
    display: block;
    unicode-bidi: embed;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: If im not mistaken here, <input type="reset"> requires a form tag to define its "scope" of what to reset ? 

Edit: But clearly that is what i would suggest aswell since its more semantic correct and there is no reason to create javascript to make this action.

Comment: Have tried this, however it is now not displaying in the browser, may there be a reason why this is happening? EDIT this now works perfectly! Thank you :)